# How does $char(F)=2$ change the basis or dimension for skew-symmetric matrices?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, proof-verification

First, let $W$ be the subspace of all $n\times n$ skew-symmetric matrices over a field $F$ (that is, $\forall C\in W, C^T=-C$). I know that that implies that $C_{ii}=-C_{ii}$ along the diagonal. Thus, $2C_{ii}=0 \implies C_{ii}=0$ if char$F\neq2$.

I then go on to show that $W$ has a basis of the form $\{A_{ij}-A_{ji} | a_{ij}=1, a_{i'j'}=0, \forall i'\neq i, \forall j'\neq j, i\neq j\}$. Still, how does this change if char$F=2$? Without the knowledge that $C_{ii}=0$, would the dimension be larger?

**Edit, My guess**: My guess is that if char$F$=2, the basis now has to include matrices with diagonal entries as well $\implies$ the dimension of $W$ will be $\frac{n^2-n}{2}+n=\frac{n^2+n}{2}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is correct: over a field of characteristic 2, your definition of skew-symmetric matrices is the same as symmetric matrices, which have dimension $n(n+1)/2$.